# Batch writing file names to a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-listing

I have a folder "C:/files" it will have say 10 files in it how would I write the files name to a text file called files.txt. I need it so the names are all in septate lines so it will look something like this.

```
file1
file2
file3
ect
```

Thanks if any one can help.

Comment: from command prompt: dir /b > filelist.txt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the folder (`cd` into it, or simple in the folder, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+`Right click` and select `Open command window here`), you can run the following dos command:

```
Dir /b *.* > list.txt
```

P.S. if you need the full path of each file, you can add extra `/s` option:

```
Dir /s /b *.* > list.txt
```

Comment: Do i just change Dir with the dir like "C:/files"

Comment: @09stephenb No, `Dir` here is the command. You need to `cd` into the folder first and then run such command. Updated the answer.

Comment: @09stephenb That's needlessly complicated. Why not do a simple `dir /b %CD%\*.* > list.txt`?

Comment: @09stephenb I have added another way to enter into the folder without using `cd`. Check out the updated answer.